# Let $K(x,t):\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative measurable function. Prove the following.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Please give me a hint not whole solution:

**The Problem:**
Let $K(x,t):\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative measurable function such that
$$F(x) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} K(x,t)dt \in L(\mathbb{R})$$

> - (a) For $f \in L(\mathbb{R})$ show that
>     $$g(x) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}K(x,t)f(t)dt$$
>     is measurable and $g \in L(\mathbb{R}).$

**What I have done:**

Since 
$F(x)\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$
then

$$ \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}F(x)dx<\infty \Rightarrow  \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\vert \int K(x,t)dt \vert dx<\infty$$

but $K(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^{+} $ so

$$ \Rightarrow  \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} \int K(x,t)dt  dx<\infty\Rightarrow  \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} (\int K(x,t)dx)  dt<\infty$$

Since 
$\int K(x,t)dx>0$
so we can conclude that
$\int K(x,t)dx<\infty.$

Now we want to show to show that $g(x)\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ so we know that $\vert K(x,t)f(t)\vert$ is measurable so I can use Fubini theorem so

$$ \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\vert \int K(x,t)f(t)dt \vert dx\leq \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} \int K(x,t)\vert f(t)\vert dt dx \\= \int\int K(x,t)\vert f(t)\vert dx dt= \int\int K(x,t)\vert f(t)\vert dx dt\leq M\int K(x,t)dx  $$
where 
$\int\vert K(x,y)\vert dt<M$.
Therefore,
$$g\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}).$$

> - (b) Compute
>     $$\sup\limits_{\Vert f\Vert_{1}\leq 1}
>   \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} K(x,t) \vert f(t)\vert dx\, dt. $$

**What I have done:**
$$\sup\limits_{\Vert f\Vert\leq 1}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} K(x,t) \vert f(t)\vert dx\, dt\leq \sup\limits_{\Vert f\Vert\leq 1}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\vert f(t)\vert\int K(x,t)  dx\, dt=\int K(x,t)dx< +\infty$$

> - (c) Evaluate
>     $$ \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} K(x,t)f(t)dt$$
>     where $f \in L(\mathbb{R}).$

**For this Part, I couldn't do anything.**

Comment: I think that for part (c), you won't have an easy answer, unless you assume e.g. continuity of $K$ in the first variable.

Comment: @PhoemueX I edited $x\to 1$ to $x\to \infty$.
Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: For the part (a) how did you do this?
$$\int\int K(x,t)\vert f(t)\vert dx dt\leq M\int K(x,t)dx$$
What do you mean with $f\in L(\mathbb{R}$? It means $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$? I think $f$ should be in $L^\infty$

Comment: @PhoemueX $f\in L^{1}$.
Also, for the first question because $f\in L^{1}$ fo it is finite.

Comment: If you don't understand my answer, please say why.

Comment: Consider the special case $k(x,t)=k_1(x) k_2 (t)$ The answer to c) becomes $c \int k_2 (t) f(t) dt$ where c is the limit of $k_1(x)$ if it exists. I my opinion the question is too general to have meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) The conclusion here is false. Proof: Let $K(x,t) = t^{-1/2}\chi_{(0,1)^2}(x,t).$ Then $F(x) = 2\chi_{(0,1)}(x),$ so $F\in L^1.$ But if we let $f(t) = t^{-1/2}\chi_{(0,1)}(t),$ then $f\in L^1,$ but $g(x) = \infty$ for $x\in (0,1).$ Thus $g\notin L^1.$

(b) The example I gave in (a) shows that the supremum here can be $\infty.$ You made a mistake in the last step of "What I have done".

(c ) There are functions $g\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ such that $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)$ fails to exist; in fact the behavior of $g$ can be rather wild at $\infty.$ Fix such a $g.$ Then define

$$K(x,t) = \frac{g(x)}{1+t^2}, \,\, f(t) = \frac{1}{1+t^2}.$$

Then

$$\tag 1 \int_{\mathbb R} K(x,t)f(t)\,dt = g(x)\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2}\,dt.$$

Since $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)$ fails to exist, the limit in $(1)$ fails to exist.

One question for you: Are sure this problem is stated correctly? Where is it from? It doesn't feel right. At any rate, I've answered the questions as stated.

Comment: I accept (a). Your counterexample is OK for me. But what about b and c.

Comment: How is my action in b

Comment: What does $\|f\|$ mean in b)?

Comment: norm in $L^{1}$. I edited.

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari I've explanded my answer.